# Where can I find some beginners to learn and work with?

Tags: java

I am very new to game programming. I am currently studying Java (Android mainly) and I know what it takes to make a game, as well as how to render it via OpenGL. Finding some others at nearly my level I think would motivate me more and give me some experience to working with others. Do you know a good place to find some people?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google "<your city> gamedev meetup" and see if anything comes up.

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking at the [GDNet Help Wanted](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/8-help-wanted/) forums and/or the [TIGSource forums](http://forums.tigsource.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I like this forum http://www.java-gaming.org/

Comment: not working ...

Comment: Sorry, wrong url. It´s www.java-gaming.org